# Drag particular part from a list in ul using jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a list containing text and arrows. I want to drag or sort arrows in such a way that :

1. They can be dragged from 1 list to other.
2. The red arrow cannot come before green arrow i.e red arrow always above green and if someone try to drag above it , it should not be possible and it resides below red only.

> **This is what i have tried so far:**

```js
$("ul.droptrue").sortable({
  connectWith: "ul"
});
```

```css
.green {
  color: green
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

li,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul class="droptrue">
  <li>i am a text 1 <i class="fa fa-arrow-left red"></i> </li>
  <li>i am a text 2 <i class="fa fa-arrow-left green"></i> </li>
  <li>i am a text 3 </li>
  <li>i am a text 4 </li>
  <li>i am a text 5 </li>
  <li>i am a text 6 </li>
</ul>
```

> **Problem:**

Right now the whole list  is dragging and I want only arrow to drag.

Thanks in Advance

Happy Coding.

Comment: "*The red arrow cannot come before green arrow i.e red arrow always above green and if someone try to drag above it , it should not be possible and it resides below red only.*" this request is bit confusing, can you clear what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`update()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) event and compare offset of both arrows, if condition doesn't match then use [`cancel()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel) method to cancel sorting.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.droptrue li").sortable({
    connectWith: "li",
    items: "> i",
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var redArrow = $('.fa.fa-arrow-left.red').offset().top;
      var greenArrow = $('.fa.fa-arrow-left.green').offset().top;
      if (redArrow >= greenArrow) {
        $("ul.droptrue li").sortable("cancel");
        console.log("Red arrow cannot be greater than Green arrow")
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.green {
  color: green
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

li,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  width: 100px
}

li div {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul class="droptrue">
  <li>
    <div>i am a text 1</div> <i class="fa fa-arrow-left red pull-right"></i> </li>
  <li>i am a text 2 <i class="fa fa-arrow-left green pull-right"></i> </li>
  <li>i am a text 3 </li>
  <li>i am a text 4 </li>
  <li>i am a text 5 </li>
  <li>i am a text 6 </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Edit:** added `items: "> i"` ([item selector](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items))  in `sortable()` this will specify which element inside the parent element should be sortable.

Comment: Hey abhishek , I am facing a problem, If I am keeping my text part inside a div then I am able to drag that as well. Is there a way to stop the text to drag when kept inside a div??

Comment: Each and every element within `ul.droptrue li` will be sortable.

Comment: did you find anything ?

Comment: I have updated my answer check once, you will need to add `items: "> i",` this will bind `sortable function` only on `i` element.